# VS Code Auto Import Prefers react-router over react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on a React project and I'm having an issue with the auto-import feature in Visual Studio Code.

When I'm trying to import a named export from the `react-router-dom` package (for example - `useLoaderData`), VS Code's auto-import tool keeps suggesting `react-router` instead, even though `react-router` is not installed in my project.

Here are the things I have already tried:

- I have only `react-router-dom` listed as a dependency in my `package.json`. There's no `react-router` in my `package.json`.
- I double-checked all my existing import statements and they are all correctly importing from `react-router-dom`.
- I've updated my VS Code to the latest version.
- I've tried to modify my ESLint import rules but no luck.
- I've tried disabling and re-enabling the JavaScript/TypeScript
  IntelliSense and it didn't help.

Despite all this, VS Code still suggests `react-router` over `react-router-dom` for any named exports. The problem is in path autosuggestion not in the package itself I think, because manually importing `useLoaderData` from `react-router-dom` works as expected.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how I could fix it?